# Can a Vuetify data table be hidden if it has no results?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify data table in a card with a filter, and want the entire card to disappear if the filter gives no responses (meaning the data table has no results). I am filtering using [this method](https://github.com/frontid/vuetify-2-data-table-multi-filter/blob/master/src/components/filter-at-column/filter-at-column.vue).

[image: I want this card to be hidden if no records are found]

The cards are created in a `v-for`

```
      <v-col v-for="datasource in datasources" :key="datasource.id" cols="6" >
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
           ...
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle>{{ datasource.name }}</v-card-subtitle>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-data-table
                  dense
                  :headers="datasource.config.headers"
                  :items="datasource.config.data"
                >
                </v-data-table>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
```

Ideally, I could just include `<v-card v-if='SOMETHING EMITTED WHEN TABLE IS EMPTY'>` but I'm not sure how to have the data table emit when everything is filtered.

Comment: Do you mean that `datasources > 0` and user or what ever happen it fall to 0? 
If so `v-if="datasources > 0"` 

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wish it was that easy, but the datasources aren't what's being filtered, rather the data within each datasource. Also, the filter doesn't change the datasources object.

Comment: Then a `computed` value or a `watch` will maybe help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. It is certainly not the cleanest but it got the job done for me.

I created the methods below. It is entirely independent of the datasource filter, and just uses the same input that I use for the datasource filter (the org object).

```
methods: {
    hasAnyValues(org, datasource) {
      if(org == null){
        return true;
      } else if (this.checkForOrgs(org, datasource)) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
    checkForOrgs(org, datasource){
      for(let i = 0; i < datasource.config.data.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(datasource.config.data[i].client_id) == org.id){
          return true;
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
}
```

I then used this method in a `v-if` statement where I create the cards in the template:

```
<v-col v-for="datasource in editedDatasources" :key="datasource.id" cols="6" >
        <v-card elevation="5" v-if="hasAnyValues(selectedOrg, datasource)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <template slot="no-results">
            <div class="no-data-wrapper">
                <div class="pa-15">
                    <img src="../../../assets/images/search-icon.svg" width="40px" height="42px" alt="">

                    <h3> No matching result </h3>
                    <p>
                        Sorry! We could not find any invoice that matches<br>
                        your search term.
                    </p>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <v-btn color="primary" outlined class="add-supplier">
                            Try Different Search
                        </v-btn>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).